# Array with multiple Objects with expire-timers fails

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, closures

I am making a game in HTML5, and now I just got a disturbing problem.

In my game I have an Array with all the particles, all the particles have expire-timers, with different random generated delays.

When the expire-timers expire they delete there own Object with the Array.splice() function, that causes trouble, since the Array.splice() function will mess up the order of the Array.

First I had the function like this:
(n = Blood particles to spawn, and x and y = starting point.)
(All particles is spread random directions from the middle, and then they are decelerated by friction)

```
function spawnBlood(x, y, n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var tetra = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) * (180 / Math.PI)
        var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 3

        var j = particles.length
        particles.push({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            vx: Math.cos(tetra) * speed,
            vy: Math.sin(tetra) * speed,
            r: 1.5,
            angle: 0,
            expireTimer: setTimeout(function(j) {
                return function() {
                    particles.splice(j, 1)
                }
            }(j), Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 500),
        })
   }
}
```

Then I had the function like this and did not have the splice function anymore so that won't make trouble with the Arrays order, but still one problem, when looping through the array to change x and y values for example to apply friction it fails. The fail is caused by that it can't define values from null:

```
function spawnBlood(x, y, n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var tetra = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) * (180 / Math.PI)
        var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 3

        particles.push({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            vx: Math.cos(tetra) * speed,
            vy: Math.sin(tetra) * speed,
            r: 1.5,
            angle: 0,
            expireTimer: setTimeout(function(i) {
                return function() {
                    particles[i] = null

                    for (var j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
                        if (particles[particles.length - 1] == null) {
                            particles.splice(particles.length - 1, 1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }(i), Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 500),
        })
   }
}
```

I had a similar problem when making expire-timers for my own audio function in the game but tricked the Errors by replacing null with new Audio(""). Since this is related to objects that doesn't work, so I wonder if there might be a similar way to make fake Objects that do not return Errors if they don't have the specified value. An example:

For Objects in this case this will throw an Error:

null.x *= friction     <---- friction = 0.8 though, will throw an Error

But it works with the fake new Audio when its about audio:

new Audio().play()     <---- Won't throw an Error

Is there any way to make a fake Object that doesn't return error if it doesn't have the specified value as in the example x? Or is this the wrong way, is there maybe another solution that won't mess up the Array and the Objects?

Thanks.

---

```
function spawnBlood(x, y, n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var tetra = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) * (180 / Math.PI)
        var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 3

        particles.push(new function() {
            this.x = x
            this.y = y
            this.vx = Math.cos(tetra) * speed
            this.vy = Math.sin(tetra) * speed
            this.r = 1.5
            this.angle = 0
            this.expireTimer = setTimeout(function(self) {
                return function() {
                    particles.splice(particles.indexOf(self), 1)
                }
            }(this), Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 500)
        })
    }
}
```

Ok FINALLY!

@tewathia - Is this a good solution or can it be improved, I mean like isn't there any other way than using "new function()" to make an object that can retrieve it's own "this"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried keeping a dummy object (with all properties set to 0) in place of the particle element that you want to delete? Replace `particles[i] = null` with

```
particles[i] = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    vx: 0,
    vy: 0,
    r: 0,
    angle: 0
};
```

Another solution might be keeping the `particles[i] = null` line, but modifying the code, where you apply the friction to the `x` and `y`, to check whether the object in question has those properties or not.

```
if(particles[i].hasOwnProperty('x') && particles[i].hasOwnProperty('y')){
//apply friction
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought the same thing but then we come to drawing. :(

Comment: And alot more, I found a solution, to make an own index variable that counts the indexes and use that to define which parent it's going to delete.

Comment: That solution doesn't seem to be so good because I need to do this without using outer variables.

Comment: @Murplyx I realize there might be quite a lot of code required, but could you create a fiddle for this? I'm not quite sure I understand why this solution doesn't work(what do you mean by 'then we come to drawing')?

Comment: Then yet one more solution, to use: particles.splice(particles.indexOf(this), 1)

Comment: I don't know if it's so good either, I have a bad feeling about that function. what do you think about the upper comment solution?

Comment: The `particles.splice(particles.indexOf(this), 1)` one? I don't see how it would help, you'd still be messing up the Array order, and wasn't that the main problem to begin with?

Comment: Yes it will but, it does not matter. Because each delete there selves. The problem with the Array messing up was that the expire-timers would delete other objects than there selves and that would create trouble. But since this solution don't go by the Array index, it goes to find where it is in the Array so I think it kinda works anyway.

Comment: Sorry for being so complicated, I can't almost understand my self

Comment: The only problem is that I'll have to put those "hasOwnProperty" checks on alooot of places

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658223/javascript-item-splice-self-out-of-list

Comment: This link is something a bit about my problem except his problem is not in a closure :(

Comment: If deleting the correct element was the only problem, then `particles.splice(particles.indexOf(this), 1)` looks good to me. I've tried using it, and it seems to be working fine

Comment: Good thinking of your solution, thanks to your ideas I came up with an improved solution finally, check the other answer on the page here (I posted it).

Comment: What do you think about it?

Comment: By the way I'll accept your answer since you was the only one taking a look at the problem, and thanks for your time

Comment: @Murplyx Your solution looks good, and I'm glad I could help. Just one small thing though, it might improve readability if you define a new [JS class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) (`function Particle(){//...}`) and then push newly created instances(`new Particle(x, y, tetra, speed)`) to your `particles` array.